# Collection in kotlin now working as it should

Tags: list, kotlin, collections

Im quite new to kotlin and was wondering why this block of coding isnt executing.

```
fun sayhello(greeting:String, itemstogreet:List<String>){
    itemstogreet.forEach {itemtogreet ->
        println("$greeting $itemtogreet")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val x = listOf("kotlin","python","java")
    sayhello(greeting="Hi",x)
}
```

Im expecting a "hi kotlin, hi python" result  but I keep getting this error:

```
Kotlin: Expecting ')'
```

Why is that?

Comment: Your code runs fine as posted after you modified the `:`.

Answer (score 0):

In **Kotlin**, specify **named parameters** using `=` not `:`

```
fun sayhello(greeting:String, itemstogreet:List<String>){
    itemstogreet.forEach {itemtogreet ->
        println("$greeting $itemtogreet")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val x = listOf("kotlin","python","java") 
    sayhello(greeting="Hi",x)  // named parameter
}
```

I tested the above code here: https://play.kotlinlang.org/

Output

```
Hi kotlin
Hi python
Hi java
```

Comment: when I do that though I get a Kotlin: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public fun sayhello(): Unit defined in root package
public fun sayhello(greeting: String, itemstogreet: List<String>): Unit defined in root package in file collections.kt error

Comment: thats weird, I still get the same error on my ide even when I copy and paste your code